# understand line of code using rails bundler gem class methods: spec = Bundler.load_gemspec(Dir["./{,*}.gemspec"].first)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm trying to load a ruby on rails app called fatfreecrm (https://github.com/fatfreecrm/fat_free_crm).

Cannot run off rails development server on my machine.  Code fails due to the following line:

```
spec = Bundler.load_gemspec(Dir["./{,*}.gemspec"].first)
```

(line 32 in project Gemfile: https://github.com/fatfreecrm/fat_free_crm/blob/master/Gemfile).

Trying to diagnose the problem but having trouble understanding what this does.  In particular what directory does `["./{, *}.gemspec"` refer to?  Dont understand the `{, *}` shorthand.

Thanks 
Evan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's standard Unix shell glob syntax for a list of options that get expanded. I.e. in a Unix shell

```
foo{a, b, c}bar
```

will get expanded to

```
fooabar foobbar foocbar
```

So,

```
./{, *}.gemspec
```

will get expanded to

```
./.gemspec ./*.gemspec
```

In Ruby's `Dir::[]` those don't get expanded like in the shell, but they are treated as a pattern against which to match the filenames, similar to how a regex works.

See the documentation for `Dir::[]`, which refers to the documentation for `Dir::glob`, for details.